# finding the minimum dates from several fields via a full outer join

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Here is the problem on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6061b/2)

I have several tables FULL OUTER JOINED together. 
In this question we have simplified to just 2 tables. 
The reason for the FULL JOINS is that the production tables have lots of  different fields that are not consistent e.g dates1 might contain Revenue and Compensation whereas dates2 might contain NumHeadBangers and NumNormalBods; so doing UNION ALL between the following won't work:

```
create table dates1 
(
USERID INT,
[Date] datetime
)
insert into dates1
values
( 1, '01 jan 2012'),
( 2, '03 jan 2012')

create table dates2 
(
USERID INT,
[Date] datetime
)
insert into dates2
values
( 2, '01 jan 2012'),
( 4, '04 jan 2012')
```

For each USERID we need to find the minimum date. Here is the attempt, I've used COALESCE because in the production script there could be 4 or 5 tables joined:

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(x.USERID,y.USERID) USERID
  , CASE WHEN x.[Date] < Y.[DATE] 
        THEN x.[Date] 
        ELSE Y.[DATE] END [DATE]
FROM 
dates1 x 
FULL OUTER JOIN dates2 y 
    ON x.USERID = y.USERID
```

The above returns the following, which is wrong for user 1 as we require User1 to have a min date of 01 jan 2012. Also the above CASE statement becomes very messy once we are dealing with 4 tables.

What is a scalable script to find these dates?

A messy solution I've been using is this:

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(x.USERID,y.USERID) USERID
  , CASE 
      WHEN ISNULL(x.[Date],'1 JAN 2020') < ISNULL(Y.[DATE],'1 JAN 2020') 
      THEN ISNULL(x.[Date],'1 JAN 2020') 
      ELSE ISNULL(Y.[DATE],'1 JAN 2020') 
  END [DATE]
FROM 
  dates1 x 
  FULL OUTER JOIN dates2 y 
     ON x.USERID = y.USERID
```

[image]

Comment: Can any user appear in the *same* table more than once?   Are you interested in just the min date, or the other fields as well?  Can you change your Schema?  Will it always be exactly 4 tables?  Have you tried using CROSS APPLY to encapsulate and simplify the min of min of min?

Comment: it won't always be 4 tables; it will be between 2 and 5 tables. The tables are actually usually temp tables (does that answer the Schema question?). I've never seen or used CROSS APPLY before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I use `CROSS APPLY` to reduce *(but not eliminate)* code repetition in this type of case (min of min of min, etc) is as follows...

```
CREATE FUNCTION min_datetime (datetime1 AS DATETIME, datetime2 AS DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
  SELECT CASE WHEN datetime1 < datetime2 THEN datetime1
              WHEN datetime1 > datetime2 THEN datetime2
              WHEN datetime1 IS NULL     THEN datetime2
                                         ELSE datetime1
         END AS val
GO;

SELECT
  COALESCE(a.id, b.id, c.id, d.id, e.id)                    as id,
  [min_datetime_d_e].val                                    as date,
  a.fields,  b.fields,  c.fields,  d.fields,  e.fields
FROM
                  a
  FULL OUTER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
  FULL OUTER JOIN c ON b.id = COALESCE(a.id, b.id)
  FULL OUTER JOIN d ON c.id = COALESCE(a.id, b.id, c.id)
  FULL OUTER JOIN e ON d.id = COALESCE(a.id, b.id, c.id, d.id)
  CROSS APPLY dbo.min_datetime(a.date,               b.date) AS min_datetime_a_b
  CROSS APPLY dbo.min_datetime(min_datetime_a_b.val, c.date) AS min_datetime_b_c
  CROSS APPLY dbo.min_datetime(min_datetime_b_c.val, d.date) AS min_datetime_c_d
  CROSS APPLY dbo.min_datetime(min_datetime_c_d.val, e.date) AS min_datetime_d_e
```

**EDIT:** Slight refactor of OP's posted answer.

```
;WITH myCTE (UserID, [Date])
AS
  (
    SELECT UserID,[Date]FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT UserID,[Date]FROM table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT UserID,[Date]FROM table3
  )
      , unique_by_user (UserID, [Date])
       (
              SELECT UserID, MIN([Date]) FROM myCTE GROUP BY UserID
       )
SELECT  
    u.UserID, u.[Date]
  , x.field1, x.field2
  , y.field3, y.field4
  , z.field5, z.field6
FROM
       unique_by_user u
  LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 x  
      ON u.USERID = x.USERID 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 z  
      ON u.USERID = y.USERID 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN myCTE k  
      ON u.USERID = z.USERID
```

It would be interesting to compare the performance of the two options above.  Initially I thought the cost of processing the data twice (Once in the CTEs, then joining all the records on again in the OUTER JOINs) would make this worse.  But I'm simply not sure now, I'd love to test and compare, but I don't have time today :)

Comment: You could even make a function that takes four parameters `(id1, date1, id2, date2)` and returns a table with two fields `(id, min_date)` and so eliminate the ever growing `COALESCE(a.id, b.id, c.id, d.id, e.id)`. In reality such a function has a *very* narrow application, which means that it's more db clutter and not worth the very slight benefit this query gets. But it does hopefully give you an example to play with to get used to using `CROSS APPLY`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the case where the comparison leads to false because one side is NULL:

```
CASE WHEN x.[Date] < Y.[DATE] OR Y.[DATE] IS NULL
```

You could also try something a little simpler:

```
SELECT userid, MIN(date) FROM
(SELECT userid, date FROM dates1
 UNION ALL SELECT userid, date FROM dates2
 -- ...
) AS x
GROUP BY userid
```

Comment: ok Aaron - I was sort of hoping someone would suggest an alternative approach. As you can imagine if I carry on as is then when there are 4 tables fully joined together then the CASE statement becomes very messy. Shame there's no way to return all the non null dates from several fields so that I could then do a simple `MIN(NONNULL(date1,date2,date3,date4))`

Comment: Sorry, SQL Server has no such functionality yet. But you could try a union approach as I just updated.

Comment: ...so the only approach is a very complex CASE? I'll add to the OP an alternative (to your suggested answer) I've been using

Comment: hmmm...ok - but the reason for the FULL JOINS is to pull in lots of different fields that are not consistent in dates1, dates2 ...like dates1 might contain Revenue and dates2 might contain NumHeadBangers ; so the union all idea falls down then

Comment: Don't over-simplify. We're smart people and can deal with multiple requirements. What is frustrating is spending time on an answer, and then being told it's not correct because of some fact you didn't disclose initially.

Comment: Fine line between simplifying and over-simplifying. I have to change my production tables as I'd be sacked if I used extracts from them! Apologies for annoying you as I appreciate your help.

Comment: @whytheq - New answer added that shows a function taking into account NULLs (as per this answer) to return a min of two datetimes. Then using `CROSS APPLY` to use it repetitively in a copy-and-paste friendly way *(maintainable by humans, creatable by scripts, adaptable to 'n' tables, etc, etc)*.

Comment: check this out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bbf3b/3 ... +1 for the answer below; not had chance to work through it yet

Comment: Ok, I looked at it. Does that sqlfiddle represent a query that solves your problem? If so, put it as an answer.

Comment: you're like the all seeing sql dude Aaron - ok I'll add as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Live copy in [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e3ab/2)

The question changed a bit along the way which is not ideal but this is what I've ended up with:

```
    create table table1 
    (
      UserID int,
      [Date] datetime,
      [field1] int,
      [field2] int
    )
    insert into table1
    values
    ( 1,'01 jan 2012',10,10),
    ( 2,'03 jan 2012',20,20)

    create table table2 
    (
      UserID int,
      [Date] datetime,
      [field3] int,
      [field4] int
    )
    insert into table2
    values
    ( 2,'01 jan 2012',30,30),
    ( 4,'04 jan 2012',40,40)


    create table table3 
    (
      UserID int,
      [Date] datetime,
      [field5] int,
      [field6] int
    )
    insert into table3
    values
    ( 2,'01 jan 2012',30,30),
    ( 4,'04 jan 2012',40,40)
```

SQL of this - which is effectively the idea put forward by Aaron but slightly different as it uses a cte feeding into the full outer joins:

```
;WITH myCTE (UserID, [Date])
AS
  (
    SELECT UserID,[Date]FROM table1 GROUP BY UserID,[Date] 
    UNION
    SELECT UserID,[Date]FROM table2 GROUP BY UserID,[Date] 
    UNION
    SELECT UserID,[Date]FROM table3 GROUP BY UserID,[Date]     
  )
      , myExtraCTE(UserID, [Date])

     AS
     (
     SELECT UserID, [Date] = MAX(Date) FROM myCTE GROUP BY UserID 
     ) 
SELECT  
  COALESCE(x.UserID,y.UserID, z.UserID ,k.UserID) USERID
  , MIN(k.[Date]) [Date]
  , SUM(ISNULL(x.field1,0.0)) field1
  , SUM(ISNULL(x.field2,0.0)) field2
  , SUM(ISNULL(y.field3,0.0)) field3
  , SUM(ISNULL(y.field4,0.0)) field4
  , SUM(ISNULL(z.field5,0.0)) field5
  , SUM(ISNULL(z.field6,0.0)) field6
FROM  
  table1 x  
FROM  
  table1 x  
  FULL OUTER JOIN table2 y  
      ON y.USERID  = x.USERID
  FULL OUTER JOIN table3 z  
      ON z.USERID  = coalesce(x.USERID,y.USERID)
  FULL OUTER JOIN myExtraCTE k  
      ON k.USERID  = coalesce(x.USERID,y.USERID,z.USERID)
GROUP BY
  COALESCE(x.UserID,y.UserID, z.UserID ,k.UserID)
```

Comment: If one user appears in each table on a different date then you get `n` records in the CTE.  This can be avoided, I'll add an example to my answer...  *(It always assumes that no user ever appears more than once in any individual table?)*

Comment: Also, the fact that `k` can have multiple records will mean that your `SUM()`s will multi-count.  As formed you need `MAX()` instead.

Comment: And the because you don't use `z.UserID = COALESCE(x.UserID, y.UserID)` *(And the same again when joining on `K`)*, you can get even more rows prior to the `GROUP BY`. *[If a user has a record in Y and Z but not K, and each record has a different date, you get 4 rows to aggregate together for that user.]*

Comment: ok - I'll investigate your info shortly @Dems - this question is real interesting for me as we use FULL OUTER JOINS all the time